# Erro ao inserir dados no SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite

Olá.
Estou com problemas nesse projeto pessoal. Ao tentar salvar um produto, o SQLite não curtiu o Price, que está definido como float, mas ao salvar no db (que está definido como REAL, até alterei para NUMERIC para verificar se resolvia, mas sem sucesso), ele não salva no db. Segue a mensagem de erro, bem como o ProductActivity.

```
public class ProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        

private EditText txtBarCode;
private EditText txtName;
private EditText txtQuantity;
private EditText txtPrice;
private Button btnSave;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product);

    txtBarCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtProductBarCode);
    txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtProductName);
    txtQuantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);
    txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtProductPrice);

    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSaveProduct);

    this.clickSaveButtonListener();

}

private void clickSaveButtonListener() {

    this.btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Product productToSave = getDataProductFromForm();

            if (productToSave != null) {
                ProductController productController = new ProductController(ConnectionSQLite.getInstance(ProductActivity.this));
                long idProduct = productController.saveProductController(productToSave);

                if (idProduct > 0)
                    Toast.makeText(ProductActivity.this, "Product successfully saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(ProductActivity.this, "An exception occurred while trying to save the product. " +
                            "Remember, all fields are required and with the appropriate data type.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ProductActivity.this, "Please, fill in all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private Product getDataProductFromForm(){

    Product product = new Product();

    if (!this.txtBarCode.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        product.setId(Integer.parseInt(this.txtBarCode.getText().toString()));
    else {
        return null;
    }

    if (!this.txtName.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        product.setName(this.txtName.getText().toString());
    else {
        return null;
    }

    if (!this.txtQuantity.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        int productQuantity = Integer.parseInt(this.txtQuantity.getText().toString());
        product.setStockQuantity(productQuantity);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }

    if (!this.txtPrice.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        float productPrice = Float.parseFloat(this.txtPrice.getText().toString());
        product.setPrice(productPrice);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }

    return product;

    }
}
```

.

```
2021-02-16 17:58:35.318 4929-4929/com.gustavojw.blproductsapp E/SQLiteLog: (1) near ")": syntax error
2021-02-16 17:58:35.320 4929-4929/com.gustavojw.blproductsapp E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting =18.5
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO product() VALUES (?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:986)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:593)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:33)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1597)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1468)
        at com.gustavojw.blproductsapp.DAO.ProductDAO.saveProductDAO(ProductDAO.java:29)
        at com.gustavojw.blproductsapp.controller.ProductController.saveProductController(ProductController.java:16)
        at com.gustavojw.blproductsapp.activities.ProductActivity$1.onClick(ProductActivity.java:50)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7161)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:967)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7133)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:804)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27416)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7617)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

.

```
public long saveProductDAO(Product product){

        SQLiteDatabase dataBase = connectionSQLite.getWritableDatabase();

    try{

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("", product.getId());
        values.put("", product.getName());
        values.put("", product.getStockQuantity());
        values.put("", product.getPrice());

        long insertedProductId = dataBase.insert("product", null, values);
        return insertedProductId;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: no contentValues você precisa passar o nome da coluna, você está passando vazio, vai ficar tipo assim: values.put("NOME_DA_COLUNA", product.getId());

Comment: Perfeito! Era isso mesmo que estava faltando! Como deixei isso passar despercebido kkkk

Comment: Agora como faço para marcar sua mensagem como a resposta??

Comment: pronto, eu tinha apenas comentado por ser simples, mas agora só descer e marcar como correto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No contentValues você precisa passar o nome da coluna, você está passando vazio, vai ficar tipo assim:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("NOME_DA_COLUNA", product.getId());
```